# Python email header strange behavior

Tags: python, python-2.7, email-headers

Python email header decoder for python2.7 or python3 seems to have some strange behavior in switching between encoded and unencoded text.

```
from email.header import decode_header
print decode_header("=?ISO-8859-1?B?QA==?=example.com");
print decode_header("=?ISO-8859-1?B?QA==?= example.com");
print decode_header("=?ISO-8859-1?Q?=40example?= .com");
print decode_header("=?ISO-8859-1?Q?=40example?=.com");
```

Here is the result

```
[('=?ISO-8859-1?B?QA==?=example.com', None)]
[('@', 'iso-8859-1'), ('example.com', None)]
[('@example', 'iso-8859-1'), ('.com', None)]
[('=?ISO-8859-1?Q?=40example?=.com', None)]
```

In all the example inputs the encoded-text is just @ sign and it should get interpreted properly but it does not. I think the interpretation of RFC 1342 seems incorrect to me.  Python expects a space or newline to be the end of an encoded text.  I don't see this in the RFC, RFC only says space is needed between multiple encoded-texts as I read it and not between encoded-text and unencoded portions of the text.  So whenever you see "?=" you need to treat that as the end of encoded text which python does not do. I want to ask the experts if this is a bug here OR if I got this wrong?

Vijay

Comment: Your problem is reproducible only in Python 2.7. I ran your code in 3.x and got correct results. Must be a bug in 2.7. As a side note, do not add semicolons at the end of lines, they are not necessary in either version of Python.

Comment: Correction to my previous comment: Apparently, 2.7 produces correct results but 3.x does not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[RFC 2047](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2047.html#section-5) defines 3 locations in which an 'encoded-word' may appear. It requires separating whitespace in almost all cases, even between an 'encoded-word' and unencoded text, and most of the cases where separating whitespace is not required appear to be errors. The text looks like this (without [errata](https://www.rfc-editor.org/errata_search.php?rfc=2047) applied, and with formatting manually adjusted):

> An 'encoded-word' may appear in a message header or body part
> header    according to the following rules:
>
> 1. An 'encoded-word' may replace a 'text' token (as defined by RFC 822)
>    in any Subject or Comments header field, any extension message
>    header field, or any MIME body part field for which the field body
>    is defined as '*text'.  An 'encoded-word' may also appear in any
>    user-defined ("X-") message or body part header field.
>
>    Ordinary ASCII text and 'encoded-word's may appear together in the
>    same header field.  **However, an 'encoded-word' that appears in a
>    header field defined as '*text' MUST be separated from any adjacent
>    'encoded-word' or 'text' by 'linear-white-space'.**
> 2. An 'encoded-word' may appear within a 'comment' delimited by "(" and
>    ")", i.e., wherever a 'ctext' is allowed.  More precisely, the RFC
>    822 ABNF definition for 'comment' is amended as follows:
>
>    ```
>     comment = "(" *(ctext / quoted-pair / comment / encoded-word) ")"
>    ```
>
>    A "Q"-encoded 'encoded-word' which appears in a 'comment' MUST NOT
>    contain the characters "(", ")" or "
>    **'encoded-word' that appears in a 'comment' MUST be separated from
>    any adjacent 'encoded-word' or 'ctext' by 'linear-white-space'.**
>
>    It is important to note that 'comment's are only recognized inside
>    "structured" field bodies.  In fields whose bodies are defined as
>    '*text', "(" and ")" are treated as ordinary characters rather than
>    comment delimiters, and rule (1) of this section applies.  (See RFC
>    822, sections 3.1.2 and 3.1.3)
> 3. As a replacement for a 'word' entity within a 'phrase', for example,
>    one that precedes an address in a From, To, or Cc header.  The ABNF
>    definition for 'phrase' from RFC 822 thus becomes:
>
>    ```
>     phrase = 1*( encoded-word / word )
>    ```
>
>    In this case the set of characters that may be used in a "Q"-encoded
>    'encoded-word' is restricted to: `<upper and lower case ASCII letters, decimal digits, "!", "*", "+", "-", "/", "=", and "_" (underscore, ASCII 95.)>`.  **An 'encoded-word' that appears within a
>    'phrase' MUST be separated from any adjacent 'word', 'text' or
>    'special' by 'linear-white-space'.**

Comment: And yet, Python 3.x "correctly" (though, admittedly, illegally) decodes headers without linear white space separators.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed read and clarification. some email user agents that do forwarding seem to encode just "@" sign  and different webmail software show different outputs.  I think this is because in these strange casese, between Perl, PHP, Python (versions) I see different behaviors.  It looks like Python 2.7 behavior is close to normal!

Answer (score 1):

This is from page 6 of [RFC1342](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1342):

> An encoded-word may be distinguished from an ordinary "word", "text",
> or "ctext", as follows: An encoded-word begins with "=?", ends with
> "?=", contains exactly four "?" characters including the delimiters,
> and is **followed by a SPACE or newline**.  If the "word", "text", or
> "ctext" does not meet the above tests, it should be displayed as it
> appears in the message header.

So *space* or *newline* are required after encoded text.

Examples of encoded headers from the same RFC:

> ```
>    From: =?US-ASCII?Q?Keith_Moore?= <moore@cs.utk.edu>
>    To: =?ISO-8859-1?Q?Keld_J=F8rn_Simonsen?= <keld@dkuug.dk>
>    CC: =?ISO-8859-1?Q?Andr=E9_?= Pirard <PIRARD@vm1.ulg.ac.be>
>    Subject: =?ISO-8859-1?B?SWYgeW91IGNhbiByZWFkIHRoaXMgeW8=?=
>     =?ISO-8859-2?B?dSB1bmRlcnN0YW5kIHRoZSBleGFtcGxlLg==?=
> ```

Comment: While that RFC is obsoleted, it does demonstrate the general intent for encoded-words to be followed by whitespace. The whitespace issue seems to have gotten a lot more complicated in later RFCs.